# How to pass a file as an argument in linux and get the list of all files in it from file system?

Tags: bash, files, filesystems, find, arguments

Lets say I have a file by name `searchfiles.txt` with file names in it:

```
2345098.txt
2345099.txt
2345100.txt
```

and so on (100 file entries)

Now I want to list out or display all the file names that match with the filesystem files by passing above (`searchfiles.txt`) as input/argument.

How can I achieve this in Linux?

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for as "match with the filesystem files" is ambiguous. Same directory or not, Moreover, your first comment to a reply adds a new feature that you do not state in your question.

Comment: It is same dir and please include my comment to the reply

Comment: That's the other way around. When you want to clarify your question, **you** edit it and modify/add what is needed. And by the way, feel free to accept the reply that best answer to your question, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while read -r file;do [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file";done <searchfiles.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @IporSircer for your prompt response .What if (searchfiles.txt) contains partial file names like  2345098* where as complete file name is 2345098_gvhghghjgjh.txt

Comment: @satya, at that point the only sensible thing to do is, ask "Where did this `searchfiles.txt` come from?" and "How can we solve the original problem in a more sensible fashion, rather than pretending that filenames can't contain newlines or special characters?"

Comment: Hi @IporSircer  
Thanks for your quick response. It solved my  first(actual or original)problem.

Comment: If so, @satya, then please use the checkmark to indicate that this Question is Answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about the `locate` command?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list | while read line; do
locate $line;
done
```

Also, you need to remember to `updatedb` before running the `locate`.

Details from `man`:

DESCRIPTION
       locate reads one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line

Answer (score 0):

If looking in the same directory or in case full paths are given in `searchFiles.txt` , you can  try this

```
ls `cat searchfiles.txt` 2> /dev/null
```

It will ask `ls` to list all files that have the same name as the ones in the `searchfiles.txt`.

`ls` will only list those files that really exists, and issue messages for those which are missing. Redirecting error to `/dev/null` will ensure that error messages for missing files  are not printed.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumar 
It solved my additinal question asked  "What if (searchfiles.txt) contains partial file names like 2345098* where as complete file name is 2345098_gvhghghjgjh.txt"

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming no special characters in the file names**, you can use `ls` and [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html):

```
ls | comm -1 -2 - searchfiles.txt
```

However, be aware this is inherently fragile—*don't* use this in a production script.

See:

- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/135943)

Comment: `comm` needs its inputs sorted ..while `ls` may do that out of the box, there's no guarantee in regards to `searchfiles.txt`